# Прерывающиеся рамки блока

Tags: html, css

Как добится того, чтобы рамки у блока были определенной длины, то есть прерывались, не доходя то конца?

Требуемый эффект: http://gyazo.com/c87f0fd177dcde76e5d89047b86fa54b

Comment: Первое, что пришло в голову http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/4g24q9aj/

Comment: Решение в лоб http://jsfiddle.net/bfanrr7h/

Comment: Еще один вариант http://jsfiddle.net/bemulima/fqkr9ckq/5/

Comment: @bemulima, а чем он принципиально от моего варианта отличается? (а понял, я забыл записать такой же почти fiddle :) )

Comment: @eicto, видимо, отличается тем, что у вас рамка только с левой и с низу а меня со всех сторон.